# new date error on react native environment but no error on chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-chrome

I wanted to generate the date using Date constructor. I am getting my desired result on chrome but Getting NAN on react native environment. When I am using same technique and values. Why is that so?

- Screenshots Attached *

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In react you should use the format like: year, (month-1), date

You may use like

```
var g2 = new Date(2020,6,11);
```

Comment: That's ok. I know that. But why doesn't it work on react like on chrome? That was my question.